# What do I do with a kohlrabi?

Tags: vegetables, culinary-uses, kohlrabi

I've recieved several kohlrabi from my CSA, and I have no idea what to do with them. I found a recipe for a curry using kohlrabi, but it wasn't great.

Does anyone have suggestions on how to get the best out of it? Any favorite recipes?

Comment: I think this is one of the best reasons to join a CSA: it forces you to learn new recipes!

Comment: @Adam Oops - wonder why the search didn't pick that up?

Comment: @Rowland Show: because "kohlrabi" is 1 word: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kohlrabi

Comment: @Dinah Not according to http://www.riverford.co.uk/sacrewell/shop/vegetables/

Comment: @Rowland Shaw: I stand corrected. That's still why the search didn't pick it up. The other question like this one spells with without a space.

Comment: It is actually one word. From the OED: kohlrabi [kəʊl'rɑːbi] (kohlrabies) a cabbage of a variety with an edible turnip-like swollen stem...

Comment: For the record: I made a simple stir-fry with the kohlrabi, and it turned out great. It maintained a kind of crispness like water chestnuts, and had a nice mild flavor (as many have pointed out, like broccoli stems).

Comment: @Pulse or two if you believe the seed sellers: http://search.thompson-morgan.com/search?w=kohl+rabi&asug=

Comment: @Adam Shiemke: You are reporting that this question is a duplicate of itself. `:-)`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(Storage note: do not wash the bulbs before storing them; place in plastic bag in the refrigerator. Wash just before using.)

Young kohlrabi is great raw. Peel first, then

- add to salads (sliced or grated)
- serve as part of a veggie platter w/ dip
- grate it and add to slaw (but after grating it, put some salt on it & let it sit, then squeeze the water out of it)
- puree it - here's someone who really loves it pureed: http://foodiefarmgirl.blogspot.com/2007/11/recipe-what-to-do-with-kohlrabi-puree.html

Cooked kohlrabi can be steamed or boiled. Remove the skin after cooking.

You can eat the leaves, if they are still firm and green; use them within a couple of days.
Wash the leaves & remove the tough stem parts (ribs). Blanch in boiling water for a couple of minutes, drain, chop, and serve with a bit of butter, salt, and pepper. A little vinegar or lemon juice is good on them, too.

Comment: Raw is great.  Peel and slice, A few grains of salt and then eat.  Real simple, real tasty.

Answer (score 5):

I found one recipe that called for it to be cubed, salt to taste, and drizzled with olive oil and baked until tender. That's the only way I've prepared it and I thought it was great. Go to the recipes section of [Doe Run Farm](http://doerunfarm.com/) (the CSA we get our veggie box from), and you'll find the Kohl Rabi recipe.

Answer (score 5):

I used to eat them like apples when I was a child, I still like the raw kohlrabi in salads. Basically, it's a sweet'ish/spicy turnip/cabbage/raddish so you can do with it, more or less anything you can do with those three vegetables.

As I said. it's great in salads, it can be steamed or added to stews, deep fried etc. The leaves are also excellent in salads and can also be cooked like spinach.

It's a very versatile and tasty vegetable.

Answer (score 3):

Most people don't realize that Kohlrabi and Broccoli are in fact different cultivars of the same species of plant (along with cabbage, cauliflower, kale and a bunch of other plants). So it's not just *like* a broccoli stem - it *is* a broccoli stem :)

I have two favorite uses for Kohlrabi - sliced thinly and used in asian-style wok dishes in a creme soup - just sautee some garlic and leek in butter and olive oil, add chopped Kohlrabi, some white wine, 1 liter of stock and cook until tender, then puree.

Answer (score 2):

You can peel it and slice it, add some lemon and salt and eat it raw as a fresh salad. It goes very well with fresh green apple, lettuce and a cold potato salad. It's highly recommended to eat fresh and not cooked. You need to make sure you peel it properly first though.

Answer (score 2):

We sliced it into about 1 inch square pieces (like a french fry but bigger) and then just lightly browned them in a bit of olive oil over high heat.

Answer (score 1):

It's a lot like a broccoli stem or a cauliflower. Steam, Saute, or Braise.

Answer (score 0):

I grow kohlrabi and beets, use the kohlrabi instead of cabbage in borsht, yum.  Also eat it raw a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the allready mentioned possibility of eating it raw, I like to make a Kohlrabi sauce to go along with pasta.

Peel and slice the Kohlrabi into slivers. Saute it with a little oil. Spice with salt and pepper. Add fresh small cut dill. Finish off with cream.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the other excellent answers (basically, use it like broccoli stems :)), it's excellent [braised](http://www.food.com/recipe/Elegant-Braised-Kohlrabi-118199).